# How to Migrate Azure DataFactory(v2) Job to another DataFactory(2)

Tags: azure, copy, migration

How to move all existing job to another Azure Datafactory.
I am trying to move existing job from one data Factory to another but not able to find the solution any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy import/export facility.

I recommend connecting your Data Factories to source control (GIT). You can then copy and paste the JSON definitions between the two repo's using a text editor.

For propagating pipelines between environments, you can look in to the documentation for [CI/CD in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment).